# Loggin linked calling stored procedure

Tags: mysql

If a user is logged into MySQL, after login can it automatically run the default stored procedure? Or just one function which shows me a report?

(Without a MySQL connector.)

Answer (score 0):

See if [*`init_connect`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) (in my.cnf) will provide that functionality.  Unfortunately it will run for all users except `root`.

Comment: Hi. I haven't understand. Can you explain better or more detailed?

Comment: This is a good answer. And then in that stored proc, figure out the username

Comment: I got this to work fine in 5.7.13.  However, it would not work in 5.6.24 or 5.6.31. When I say *this to work* I mean anything to work. For `root` one would not want it to work anyway due to technical reasons too long to comment about.